# Disable Edit Series but leave Edit Item enabled

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-calendar

I am limited to Sharepoint 2007 out-of-the-box and I do not have Sharepoint Designer available to me. I am trying to make an appointment scheduler. I have created a Calendar List and pre-populated it with recurring events every weekday at 0800, 0900, 1000, 1100, etc. each titled "Available". The calendar view displays only appointments that have not been reserved. The premise is that a customer would click on an Available appointment, add their information, and save the appointment.

My question: is there a way, within my limitations, to disable "Edit Series" on the list items (appointments) while leaving "Edit Item" available to the customers?